# How do I run preg_replace matches through function?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I run preg_replace matches through function, before replacing them?

```
myfunction($value =  NULL) {
}

preg_replace('/(?<=\[\[)(.*?)(?=\]\])/', myfunction('$0'), 'aaa[[replace]]aaa')
```

The problem with the code above, is that `$0` is not a variable while it's in a function. But when it's returned, it changes to a matched string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to pass it through function first